# Prompt user for sentence and store it without being disturbed by spaces

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting

I have a bash function that prompts user to input certain data.
I tried it with first name, last name, birthday etc.

Data that is mostly represented in one sentence.

When I ask for street + no. the function breaks, because it
can't handle spaces.

```
askForData 'Please enter your street and number' STREET
```

I get following error.

```
Please enter your street and number: ExampleStreet 123
func_askForData: line 21: 123: command not found
```

How can I extend my function to accept sentences?

file: func_askForData

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage askForData "Prompt for value" VARIABLE
# Prints out prompt and stores input in VARIABLE
# 
# Prompt is printed till non-empty input is made.

function askForData()
{
local PROMPT=${1}
eval local VAR_NAME=${2}

local CONTINUE=true
while ${CONTINUE}
    do
        read -p "${PROMPT}: " VAR_VALUE
        if [ -z "$VAR_VALUE" ]; then
            CONTINUE=true
        else
            CONTINUE=false
            eval ${VAR_NAME}="${VAR_VALUE}"
        fi
    done
}
```

**Additional info**

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: Pity you're using an older version of bash. bash 4 has associative arrays which would make things much neater.

Comment: Actually I have bash 4 on my desktop machine and on sdf. I'm going to take a look at associative arrays! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
eval ${VAR_NAME}='"${VAR_VALUE}"'
```

With `eval`, you get in general a two-fold expansion. If there are any things in an `eval` statement that should be expanded only once, it's usually better to quote them in such a way that the first expansion does nothing (except for quote removal) and the second expansion does the main job. In this concrete case, the first expansion yields

```
STREET="${VAR_VALUE}"
```

which is then executed correctly during the second expansion. If you try to do it the other way round, it's difficult to ensure that the result of the first expansion remains unchanged during the second expansion.

I also have the impression that the first `eval` (before `local VAR_NAME=${2}` is superfluous.

Comment: Sry, but your answer changes nothing. The first eval is needed to pass the prompt argument not only as string, but also as variable like `"${PROMPT}"`

Comment: It works for me. Try it: If `$2` consists only of alphanumerical characters, there is no difference between `local VAR_NAME=${2}` and `eval local VAR_NAME=${2}`, and if `$2` contains, e.g., spaces, the function will break anyway. The second `eval` is necessary, you just have to get the quoting right.

Comment: Thank you! I had the function embedded in another script that had a similiar `eval`. I fixed it accordingly.